# PHP Class chaining

Tags: php, class, symfony

I am using SMoney package from Picoss, my code :

```
$http = new HttpClient("token","url");
$api = new SMoneyApi($http);

$profile = new \Picoss\SMoney\Entity\Profile();
$profile->setCivility(0);
$profile->setLastName("Doe");
$profile->setFirstName("John");
$profile->setEmail("johndoe@gmail.com");
$profile->setPhoneNumber("000000000");

$user = new \Picoss\SMoney\Entity\User();
$user->setAppUserId(time());
$user->setProfile($profile);
$user->setType(1);

$api->user()->save($user); // works
```

How can I use on my element this code for get all errors:

```
$api->user()->getErrors(); // works
```

I would like make :

```
$api->user()->save($user)->getErrors(); // doesn't works
```

But i can't, have you solutions ?

Informations :

- SMoneyApi have method user() which extends ApiUser
- APIUser extends ApiBase
- ApiBase (abstract class) have method :
  getErrors();
- getErrors extends SMoneyError

https://github.com/picoss/SMoney/blob/master/src/SMoneyError.php

==

Solved :

```
$d = $api->user();
$apis = $d->save($user);
var_dump($d->getErrors());
```

Thanks

Comment: Push any errors to an array or string and `return` those errors if any errors exist through `getErrors()`, if no errors exist, then you'd `return false`?

Comment: Method exist for get all errors, but i don't know how can i use it. If save function have not error, return null, and i woud like get errors from headers php.